# Writing and running tests. ImportError: No module named generic

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I'm new to [tests in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/testing/overview/). And I need to write a couple.

Django version 1.9.7.
OS: `Linux version 4.2.0-42-generic (buildd@lgw01-54) (gcc version 5.2.1 20151010 (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) ) #49-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 28 21:26:26 UTC 2016`

My simple test code is:

```
cat animal/tests.py

from django.test import TestCase
from animal.models import Animal 

class AnimalTestCase(TestCase):
    def say_hello(self):
        print('Hello, World!')
```

I execute it in this way `./manage.py test animal`

And the following error arise:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 13, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/path-to-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/path-to-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/path-to-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/path-to-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/path-to-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/path-to-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autofixture/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from autofixture.base import AutoFixture
  File "/path-to-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autofixture/base.py", line 7, in <module> 
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.generic import GenericRelation
ImportError: No module named generic
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you post your Animal model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your installed version of django-autofixture does not support Django 1.9, because it has out of date imports for `GenericRelation`.

Try upgrading to the latest version. The project's [changelist](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-autofixture/blob/d38ae8feaf159178ebea65fbc343970e6f440258/CHANGES.rst) says that Django 1.9 support was added in version 0.11.0.

In order for Django to run your method in your `AnimalTestCase`, you need to rename it so that it begins with `test_`:

```
class AnimalTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_say_hello(self):
        print('Hello, World!')
```

Comment: I upgraded django-autofixture and there is no error anymore. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the hint about the `test_` prefix!

Answer (score 2):

You have the wrong import, the correct import is from

```
django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation
```

But that seems to actually come from django auto-fixtures rather than from your own code. The good news is that you don't need auto-fixtures for this sort of simple tests. Just say good bye to it.

Comment: I upgraded django-autofixture and there is no error anymore. You said that I don't have to use django-autofixture. Then, what do I have to use instead?

Comment: Well nothing actually! For example the test you have shown doesn't need any sort of fixtures whatsoever!